# Creating a Twitter Follow List Item in Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

Trying to get a list item(li) working so when clicked it opens the Twitter Follow dialogue box. I have tweaked the code slightly to try and get it working with a link within a list item but doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Can anyone spot the error?

```
<li class="main_news">
<a href="https://twitter.com/amazon">
    <script>
        ! function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
            if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
    </script>
</li>
```

The code is taken from
https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#follow

Answer (score 0):

Custom styled anchor that still opens the "official" Twitter popup.

Based on  https://geekgoddess.com/use-custom-graphic-for-twitter-follow-button/

```
<li class="main_news">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/follow?screen_name=amazon">Follow @amazon</a>
</li>
<script src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excellent-but don't want to use the Twitter button but my own styling set in "main_news", any solution to using the twitterFollow() in step 2?

Comment: Edited, now you can style it and the popup will still work.